# IBM Worklight 6.1 - App Center Error on iOS 6.1

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I am using IBM Worklight 6.1. with App Center.
I deployed the App Center with my server URL, and deployed my application into the App Center.

This works fine on Android and iOS 7, but in my iOS 6.1 phone, but when I try to login inside the App Center Application, I have the error popup: `Connection Failed. Check your connection details (Could not connect to the server).`

I tested with a Worklight server deployed under https.

- Does anyone have a similar issue?
- Is this a known App Center issue with iOS6?
- Any solution?

Comment: Have you tried debugging the AppCenter application itself? Connect it to XCode and watch the trace. You may get some useful hints as to the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your iOS6 device can access the App Center successfully? Is it on the same network? One thing you can attempt is trying to access the app center console through the mobile web browser of the iOS6 device to see if maybe it is a networking issue

Comment: they are in the same network, and it works from the mobile browser. I haven't debugged the AppCenter itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you use SSL, the problem might be in the web server. We found that iOS 6 was using TLS v1.2, and iOS 7 was using TLS v1.0 for the SSL handshake.

Hence, the web server (or, depending on your network infrastructure, the proxy or firewall) needs to support both TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2 in order to open an SSL connection on iOS 6 and iOS 7. If it only supports TLS 1.0, then iOS 7 works but iOS 6 does not work.